# Wait for observables to complete before calling next one

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using RxJS the following way and I get unexpected values order. The following code can be executed in Stackblitz.

EDIT - Simplified code. We could simplify to 2 simple observers to the same behaviorsubject that receive data in different order.

```
this.state$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>({ a: null, b: null });

const obs1 = this.state$
  .subscribe((value) => {
    console.log('obs 1', value);
    if (value.a == 1) this.state$.next({ a: 2, b: 3 });
  });

const obs2 = this.state$.subscribe((value) => console.log('obs 2', value));

this.state$.next({ a: 1, b: 1 });
```

This is what the logs look like

```
obs 1 {a: null, b: null}
obs 2 {a: null, b: null}
obs 1 {a: 1, b: 1}
obs 1 {a: 2, b: 3}
obs 2 {a: 2, b: 3}
obs 2 {a: 1, b: 1}
```

I would expect the observers of the same behavior subject to receive emitted values in the same order, wherever these values come from.

Previous code

```
class sampleState {
  a: any;
  b: any;
}

const initialState: sampleState = {
  a: null,
  b: null,
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: ``,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  protected _state$: BehaviorSubject<sampleState>;
  state$: Observable<sampleState>;

  constructor() {
    this._state$ = new BehaviorSubject<sampleState>(initialState);
    this.state$ = this._state$.asObservable();

    this.select((state) => state.a).subscribe((value) => {
      console.log('a ' + value);
      if (value == 1) this.setState({ b: 3 });
    });

    this.select((state) => state.b).subscribe((value) => {
      console.log('b ' + value);
    });

    this._state$.subscribe((value) => console.log(value));

    this.setState({ a: 1, b: 1 });
  }

  public get state() {
    return this._state$.getValue();
  }

  public setState(newState: any) {
    this._state$.next({
      ...this.state,
      ...newState,
    });
  }

  public select<K>(mapFn: (state: sampleState) => K): Observable<K> {
    return this._state$.asObservable().pipe(
        map((state: sampleState) => mapFn(state)),
       distinctUntilChanged()
    );
  }
}
```

I get the following logs

```
{a: null, b: null}
{a: 1, b: 3}
{a: 1, b: 1}
```

while I would expect

```
{a: null, b: null} // initialisation
{a: 1, b: 1} // setState
{a: 1, b: 3} // if a == 1 => set b = 3
```

It appears the first setState is not completed before calling the next one. Is there a way to change this behavior so the states change sequentially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this behavior because all of the operations are synchronous and you are emitting a new value from within your "select a" subscription, which causes the subscribe logic to be executed recursively.

To prevent the recursive behavior, you can utilize the [`asapScheduler`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/asapScheduler) like this:

```js
this.state$ = this._state$.pipe(observeOn(asapScheduler));
```

Now, update your `select` method to use `this.state$` instead of `this._state$` and you should be good to go.

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-77189343?file=src%2Fmain.ts&devtoolsHeight=100) you can check out.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To complement the answer from @BizzyBob this is what happens.

There are 3 consumers of the stream represented by `this.state$` (or `this._state$` for that matter) and these are the 3 subscriptions in the code.

Any time `this._state$` notifies something via `next` all 3 subscriptions react, in the sequence they have been registered, i.e. first `this.select((state) => state.a).subscribe(...`, then the `this.select((state) => state.a).subscribe(...` and eventually `this.state$.subscribe((value) => console.log('the object', value));`.

The last one though is the only to write on the console, hence when it receives the first notification it writes `{a: null, b: null}`.

The first notification (`this.select((state) => state.a).subscribe(...`) had previously done its job of notifying the new value `{a: 1, b: 3}` which is then the second value that `this.state$.subscribe((value) => console.log('the object', value));` writes `{a: 1, b: 3}` on the console.

Eventually, in this synchronous order, comes `this.setState({ a: 1, b: 1 });` which causes `this.state$.subscribe((value) => console.log('the object', value));` to write `{a: 1, b: 1}`.

So, the whole thing is synchronous, but, if you look at the code, it goes first down to `this.state$.subscribe((value) => console.log('the object', value));`, then up to the first subscription that fires a new notification and then to the bottom where the last notification occurs.

Comment: Actually b:3 is set after the call to setState({ a: 1, b: 1 }), not after the initialisation {a:null, b:null} because it requires a = 1 in ` if(value == 1) this.setState({ b: 3 }); ` .  It is fine that the subscriptions happen sequencially and asynchoniously. What I need is the values to be emitted sequencially following the next calls. Here b:3 next call happens after the b:1, but the b:3 is emitted before the b:1. Apparently the previous next {a:1, b:1} is not completed yet, and the next one {a:1, b:3} is handled first before the completion of {a:1, b:1}.

Comment: In this example everything is syncrhonous. Plus `this.select((state) => state.a).subscribe((value) => {...` triggers a recursive stream, as you can appreciate if you remove `distinctUntilChange`. Therefore `this._state$.subscribe((value) => console.log(value));` consumes first all the data notified by the recursive stream and only when the recursion ends, it consumes the value notified by `this.setState({ a: 1, b: 1 });`.

Comment: I edited the question and removed the select and distincUntilChange to keep only 2 simple observers of the same behaviorsubject.